# phantomjs intercept response headers

Tags: webdriver, phantomjs, codeception

I am currently creating a test script using codeception webdriver, I decided to run this script automatically every after a specified interval to know whether or not my application is still working. With its capability on generating error logs and screenshots this automated testing tool has been helpful. But I personally think that getting response headers would be more helpful. Is there anyway I could do this without changing the frameworks I have been using? If so, could you guide me on how to implement this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up in Selenium Ruby web driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732015/element-not-found-in-the-cache-perhaps-the-page-has-changed-since-it-was-looke)

Comment: That one is using selenium, I am using phantomjs